# WebAssembly и размер клиентского файла

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли обзор сравнения размера выходного файла, сгенерированного из программы на другом языке для WebAssembly под различные типы сайтов? И, если нет, то не могли бы вы поделиться опытом о размере выходных файлов без оптимизации?